# “the server responded with a status of 405” + “Access to fetch… from origin … has been blocked by CORS policy”

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

We have two different asp.net core web api applications employing the following C# code snippet.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddUniversalCORS(this IServiceCollection services)
            => services.AddCors(setupAction => setupAction.AddPolicy("myPolicy", builder =>
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()));
```

Also, we have an Angular app that calls both web apis. Making the call to the first web api goes through flawlessly and successfully but the 2nd one fails due to the following error message:

> Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44317/api/logic/save' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>   [http://localhost:4200/pool/create]
>
> Failed to fetch.

Here it is how the POST request is made in `Promise` and the only differences between the two requests are the URL and the json payloads and the headers are the same:

```
const url = 'https://localhost:44317/api/logic/save';
     const request = {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(this.myPayload)
     };
```

So, why one of the web api calls is successful but the other one fails due to the CORS error message? Really running out of reasons to justify this issue which made us get stuck for quite a while!

We also consulted StackOverflow to find an answer for this issue but none of the answers helped, unfortunately.

**UPDATE:**
Submitting the same failed POST request in Angular by POSTMAN goes through successfully.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Here it is the status:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (). 

Please note that when I submit the same payload using POSTMAN, it goes through perfectly.

Comment: Are you sure the CORS-related code in Startup.cs in both projects is the same? Something must be different. You can review [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: So, you have a 405 problem to fix, not a CORS problem. If you fix the cause of the 405 problem, then you are likely going to find that your CORS configuration is working exactly as expected. To troubleshoot the cause of the 405 problem, check your server logs on the server side. You also need to identify if the 405 error is in response to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request, or instead if it’s in response to the POST request from your code. A 405 means Method Not Allowed, so it’s more likely in response to the OPTIONS request — and the fix is to configure the server to allow OPTIONS requests.

Comment: This is what the server logs:

Executed endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'

Comment: @sideshowbarker Marking this as a duplicate was a mistake. The answer you a gave to the other question is very generic and not helpful in this case. The real issue here is why ASP.NET Core is returning 405 to an OPTIONS request when it has been specifically told to "UseCors" (and OPTIONS requests are integral to CORS). Your other answer doesn't answer that at all.

Comment: `it goes through perfectly.` What status is returned to Postman?

Comment: @Arash In Postman, change the method to OPTIONS. That's the request that's failing in the browser. Also, can you add the code in your Startup.cs to your question?

Comment: @mjwills Postman doesn’t make an OPTIONS call. So the Postman call the OP is using isn’t emulating what the the browser is actually doing. To use Postman to emulate what the browser is actually doing would require first making an OPTIONS call with Postman rather than a POST.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bcors%5D+405 https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net-core%5D+%5Bcors%5D+405

Comment: Have a read with official .NET core docs on [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2). There are many reasons CORS can fail. It is not failing in postman because CORS isn't not applied to CURL commands. Try looking at the network tab of your developer's console and check the request and response headers in the first OPTIONS call to your api. Make sure the returned `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is present and actually set to your localhost domain without any trailing slash.

Comment: I could not find a solution so far? What change am I supposed to make in asp.net core CORS definition to get this issue addressed?

Comment: Have you tried to use `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()`, do not forget to use `app.UseCors("myPolicy")` also

Comment: @XingZou Just wondering, why should I specifically do that while the code snippet that I posted in the question is liberal enough to cover localhost:4200? I have used app.UseCors("myPolicy" already.